# DOMDocument error on loadHTML() "Empty string supplied as input"?

Tags: php, domdocument

When I remove the @ sign from my $d, $x DOMdocument variables below, I'm getting the error...

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML()
>   [domdocument.loadhtml]:   Empty string
>   supplied as input in 
>   C:\xampplite\htdocs\mysite\wp-content\plugins\myplugin\index.php
>   on line 50

On the $content variable, when I run the function below. Even though I can echo $content and get a string. What am I missing?

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'decorate_keyword');

function decorate_keyword($postarray) {
    global $post;
    $keyword = getKeyword($post);
    /*
      Even though I can echo $content, I'm getting the error referenced above.
      I have to explicitly set it to a string to overcome the error.
    */
    $content = $postarray['post_content']; 
    //$content = "this is a test phrase";
    $d = new DOMDocument();
    $d->loadHTML($content);
    $x = new DOMXpath($d);
    $nodes = $x->query("//text()[contains(.,'$keyword') and not(ancestor::h1) and not(ancestor::h2) and not(ancestor::h3) and not(ancestor::h4) and not(ancestor::h5) and not(ancestor::h6)]");
    if ($nodes && $nodes->length) {
        $node = $nodes->item(0);
        // Split just before the keyword
        $keynode = $node->splitText(strpos($node->textContent, $keyword));
        // Split after the keyword
        $node->nextSibling->splitText(strlen($keyword));
        // Replace keyword with <b>keyword</b>
        $replacement = $d->createElement('b', $keynode->textContent);
        $keynode->parentNode->replaceChild($replacement, $keynode);
    }
     $postarray['post_content'] = $d;
return $postarray;
}
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($content);` (placed above the call to `DOMDocument`) give?

Comment: @lonesomeday: it returns string(281) "If you like jasmine tea you will really like it with Jasmine Tea flavors. THis is the last ocurrence of the phrase jasmine tea within the content. If there are other instances of the keyword jasmine tea within the text what happens to jasmine tea.".

Answer (score 0):

You should input a URL string like `http://www.example.com` to `loadHTML()` instead of an array.